# java regex to not get string not ending with dot

Tags: java, regex

I m trying regex to get the strings

1. starting with **@** and
2. not ending with a **dot(.)**

For that i tried the java code([link here](http://ideone.com/klBZAU)) but this does not show any results -

```
@(\\w+)*(?<!.(.))*$
```

The string i m trying is -

```
This is a test\nAnother @pradyut@test ht@html.com\ntest\n#art\n@cool#paintings#collections
```

This should return

```
pradyut
test
cool
```

The result html ending with a .com should not return.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=@)\w+\b(?!\.)
```

In Java you have to use:

```
(?<=@)\\w+\\b(?!\\.)
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iH4eD7/1)

Comment: this is not giving a op in java - http://ideone.com/klBZAU

Comment: But that code is not using my suggested regex if you notice.

Comment: [Now check this working demo](http://ideone.com/udbRy5)

Comment: yes the matcher group was with the index 0 in my code. thanks

Comment: what could be the problem with the javascript version here - http://jsfiddle.net/8S5wb/4/

Comment: 1. Javascript doesn't support lookbehind. 2. Question was about Java so my solution is also for Java.